# ImportError: No module named ntlk

Tags: python, nlp

I have used ntlk in the past but now am unable to import it in python. The error is:

```
 *ImportError: No module named ntlk*
```

1) I checked it was still installed, it appears in pip list as the latest version

2) I checked it was still in the system path:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

The ntlk directory appears in the list of paths

3) I checked I was able to import other modules from the sys.path without issues.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it `nltk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your PYTHONPATH variable as per your installed python [2.x or 3.x]

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: What would it accomplish? Why do you believe `site-packages` aren't it PATH already?

Comment: sometimes we use multiple python installations & ImportError generally comes in when `site-packages` isn't present in the PATH variable.

So by updating `PYTHONPATH` we can include `site-packages` if not added in `PATH` variable already.

Comment: I set the PYTHONPATH variable to be the .../lib/python2.7/site-packages directory which contains nltk. I validated that it had been updated using printenv. However the problem annoyingly remains

Comment: @John what do you import exactly? Your comment shows "nltk", but your question shows "ntlk".